# Почему в JS перенос кода на новую строку меняет его поведение?

Tags: javascript

Пример 1

```
const ex1 = () => { return
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(res2=>res2.title)
                    }
```

Пример 2

```
const ex2 = () => { return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(res2=>res2.title)
                    }
```

Эти 2 примера отличаются только тем, что во втором код после return на новой строке, и уже ничего не возвращается.
Почему так ? Неужели JS чувствителен к переносам строк, даже если код один и тот же ?

Comment: Да. Гуглить «JS ASI» (automatic semicolon insertion) из-за которого возникают такие пограничные случаи. Первый код читается движком как `return; fetch(...)` и соответственно fetch даже не вызывается.

Comment: Кстати, Firefox в консоли про это даже предупреждает https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxzYP.png